# What's that theorem? All RG operators flow to directed percolation?

Tags: renormalization, phase-transition, critical-phenomena, cellular-automaton, percolation

I can't for the life of me get this theorem straight. I can remember neither the name nor it's statement and would be grateful for anyone who wants to toss out some wisdom.

It pertains to the universality class directed percolation (DP) and RG (renormalization group) operators as a general category.

It goes something like: RG operators themselves can be linked and the system flows to RG. All I really remember is that some general class of something having to do with RG turns out to be DP.

Any help would be appreciated it is really bugging me.

Comment: It might be a conjecture, a professor of critical-phenomena mentioned it in passing and I don't have their contact info.